# Наследовать класс Main

Tags: java, наследование

Можно ли наследовать класс `Main` от другого класса?

Я попытался сделать `public class Main extends Actions {` и в классе `Main` нельзя вызвать метод из класса `Actions`.

Класс `Actions`:

```
package com.company;

public class Actions {
    public void messageMainMenu(){
    System.out.println("\nВыберите пункт меню:" +
            "\n0. Выход" +
            "\n1. Заблокировать счет" +
            "\n2. Разблокировать счет" +
            "\n3. Поиск счета" +
            "\n4. Сортировка счетов" +
            "\n5. Общая сумма по всем счетам" +
            "\n6. Общая сумма по всем счетам (с отрицательным балансом)" +
            "\n7. Общая сумма по всем счетам (с положительным балансом)" +
            "\n8. Вывести информацию по всем счетам");
    }
}
```

Класс `Main`:

```
public class Main extends Actions{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    messageMainMenu(); // ТАК НЕЛЬЗЯ ВЫЗВАТЬ МЕТОД
    }
}
```

**Ответ:**

@gil9red, @Exploding Kitten, @Olmicron
Совсем забыл, что `Кроме того, вы не можете вызвать в статичном методе не статичные методы`.

Comment: Небходимо больше конкретики, а лучше [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @gil9red, добавил в топике.

Comment: в статическом методе нельзя вызывать "обычные" методы, создайте объект тогда они будут доступны

Comment: Это опечатка `public class Main {` или вы забыли указать `extends Actions`? Кроме того, вы не можете вызвать в статичном методе не статичные методы т.е. метод должен быть статичным: `messageMainMenu()`. Либо, в `main` создайте объект `Main` и у него сможете вызвать `messageMainMenu()`

Comment: @gil9red, это была опечатка, теперь добавил. Сейчас попробую. Если есть желание, добавьте как ответ на вопрос, я его приму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать экземпляр класса Main, вы же пытаетесь вызнать не статический метод из статического...

```
public class Main extends Actions {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().messageMainMenu();
    }
}
```